# Magento inventory tracking for custom options

Tags: magento, configuration, admin, product, inventory

Is there any way to do this with Vanilla magento? I know I can create a configurable product with simple products "Product A - Option1, Product A - Option2 etc". Is it more beneficial to create simple products for colors and sizes? Maybe from a reporting standpoint?

I found this http://www.mageworx.com/advanced-product-options-magento-extension.html
Would there be any drawbacks from using an extension like this?

Comment: Have you tried? Bring your experience (with the extension)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to be able to properly track stock etc then proper configurable products based on simple products to represent SKUs is the best way.

in my mind, custom options are really meant for non stock related options such as custom printing services, extra gift wrapping or other options like this.

the extension you mention is really for managing sets of custom options across multiple products and makes custom options easier to manage but does not meant that you should use custom options to track different SKUs such as products coming in a variety of colours that you hold in stock.

The quickest way to create the simple products for a configurable product via the Magento admin is to create the configurable product first then use the "quick simple product creator" option to create the simple products quickly and easily.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/welcome_to_the_magento_user_s_guide/chapter_3#creating_a_configurable_product (scroll down a bit)